# Making multiple views in a single function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

Here is my Main Controller I am using loader function as common and loading the 
menu, title and pages from each functions (index, blog etc.,) and if i want to load
two pages how can i do this ?

I mean if i want to have $url = "index"  and $url = "blog", $url = "contact"

```
<?php

    public function loader($url,$menu,$data)
    {
        $this->load->view('assets/header',$menu);
        $this->load->view($url,$data);
        $this->load->view('assets/footer');
    }

    public function index()
    {   
        $menu['menu']="home";
        $menu['title']="Home Page";
        $data='null';
        $url="index";
        $this->loader($url,$menu,$data);
    }
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask.

Comment: I mean how can if i want to pass to views like $url = index and $url = blog how can i do that ?

Comment: Make `$url` a protected variable so it's accessed like `$this->url`.

Comment: It's hard to give you a correct answer because your main function `view()` is not included so it's hard to extrapolate how this class works

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to load two or more views using the code above eg load the index view and then the blog view (or something along those lines)? Or load a view inside another?

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass the URL as a parameter of index? Like www.site.com/whatever_the_controller_is_called/blog?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes, I mean the thing you say

Comment: @MikeMiller No, The thing Ross Wilson said

Comment: Yes, @BIz, but I gave you 2 options. 1. Load a view one after the other, or 2. Load a view inside another. Which one are you trying to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your goal by changing the value of `$data` i.e

```
  $data['content']='contact'
  $this->load->view('template',$data);
```

and in your template view do this

```
   $this->load->view($content);
```

or you can also do this

```
 $url='contact'; //name of your view page here
 $this->load->view($url,$data);
```

Comment: No, it should not if i do so , it will load everytime, i should load only in a particular period function.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways. In your controller you can do:

```
    //true returns the view content as a string
    $data['view1_html'] = $this->load->view('view1',$view1_data,true);
    //then load your master view as normal
    $this->load->view('master',$data);
```

Or within your master view you can just do:

```
    <?=$this->load->view('view1');?>
```

But to just change the value of the url and therefore show a different view it would be sensible to use a different controller function:

```
    public function blog(){
    ....
    $this->loader('blog',$menu,$data);
    }
```